# While guessing a 8 digits phone number, what is the probability that at least 3 digits are guessed correctly at their position?

Tags: probability

While guessing a 8 digits phone number, what is the probability that at least 3 digits are guessed correctly at their position?

While making a guess, if we put one number on top of the other, the digits that match are considered to be guessed correctly. For example:

1234 5678  = number we are looking for

9034 0008  = a guess

In this case, 3 digits match.

I made an empiric research using Python, and the odds seem to be around 5%

Comment: Are you imposing any conditions on a "phone number"?  Like that it can't start with $0$ or such?  Regardless of that detail, each guess has a $.1$ chance of being correct (modified by any extra conditions, of course).  After that, this is a binomial process.

Comment: no condition implied, no prefix etc. all digits belong to [0,9]

Comment: Ok, so just a straight binomial distribution then.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple binomial distribution $n = 8, p = 0.1$

$$P(X >=3) = \sum_{k=3}^8\binom 8{k}0.1^k\cdot 0.9^{8-k} \approx 0.0381$$

Comment: @lulu: Thanks, better have  some coffee !

Comment: A feeling I know well.